# Static scoping in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, scoping, dynamic-scope

In the following code, `2` is printed.

```
int x = 1;
int f(int y)
{
    return x;
}

int main() {
    x = 2;
    printf("%d", f(0));
}
```

How is it happening if we have static scoping in C? Why isn't `1` printed?

Printing `2` in this case isn't a dynamic scoping, is it?

I thought that in static scoping it should take the nearest x to the function definition.

Comment: You only declare a single `x` here (as a global variable). So any modification done from anywhere in the code will affect any later use from any other place of the code.

Comment: Why would it? x is _not constant_ and is modified before it's returned.

Comment: It is taking the closest one (there's only one to choose from though) and the assignment happens before the function call so ofc it prints 2. Works as intended (TM).

Comment: Those are usually called dynamic and *lexical* scoping.

Comment: Because C and C++ (and almost every other programming language) execute code from the top to the bottom?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does take the nearest `x`, but since you only have one `x` it doesn't really matter.

If you change the code to

```
int x = 1;
int f(int y)
  {
    return x ;
  }

int main() {
    int x=2;       
    printf("%d", f(0));
}
```

so you have 2 `x`, the global one and the local one in `main` you will see `1` getting printed.

Comment: Why So , I am unable to understand.

Comment: @SurajJain Can you be more specific?

Comment: I Mean why are we not able to print that value. , i do not understand your answer.

Comment: @SurajJain By "that value" you mean the local `int x=2;` inside `main`? Because the `x` in `f` looks up the "nearest" `x` which is the global one. The lookup is done at compile time by only looking at `f` and upwards without checking at runtime where `f` was called from because that would be slow and confusing.

Comment: I mean why is the value 2 is printing , it should print 1 right because f(0) should return 1.

Comment: @SurajJain In my code the value `1` is printed because we print the global `x` which has the value `1`, but in the original code `2` is printed because the global `x` was overwritten with `x=2;` before it was printed. Are you confused because I wrote "2 `x`" in my answer?

Comment: How could it be overwritten ?

Comment: @SurajJain You start with `int x = 1;` and `x` is `1`. Then you do `x = 2;` and now `x` is `2`. I'm not sure what you are asking. We can [discuss this in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116940/c-questions-and-answers) if you want.

Comment: ANd main thing that i find faulty with your code is that you declare another `int x` in main so how can it overwrite the global x, i find this problematic.

Comment: ok so you mean global was over written in original code , why so ?

Answer (score 3):

Those are usually called dynamic and *lexical* scoping.

Lexical scoping is determined entirely at compile time, dynamic scoping at runtime.

You only have one variable named "x", so scope is irrelevant to your program.

Here's a program that would be different depending on the scoping rules:

```
int x = 0;

int f()
{
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    printf("%d\n", f(x));
}
```

Under lexical scoping, `f` returns the value of the `x` that is lexically "nearest" - the global one.
So it would print `0`;

Under dynamic scoping, `f` would return the value of the newest `x`, which is the one in `main`.
So it would print `1`.

Answer (score 2):

The scoping is moot here since you have **not** declared an `x` locally that would have otherwise *shadowed* the global `x`.

`2` is printed.

`x` is assigned in `main` to `2` immediately before `f` is called with the parameter `0`.

(Conceptually `int x = 1;` is ran before `main` is entered.)

Answer (score 1):

It is the way the compiler generates the assembly/machine code.

- first global variable X is stored in memory location "abc"
- next main is executed: global variable X at "abc" is changed to 2
- Now function f() is called:

  - function f returns the value of global variable X at "abc": being 2
- the return value of f() is printed.

So if you wanted a different X in the main-function scope, you should have made a new object, like in the answer by nwp.

Comment: "you should have made a new object, like in the answer by nwp." That's not what happens in @nwp 's code, less you're using the worlds worst compiler.

Comment: @george: true, but seeing the simplicity of the questions, I did not want to elaborate on compiler details ;)

Comment: I kind of got the impression from the last line that something like `printf("%d", f(x));` would print 2 <-- obviously you can't initialize a variable twice, so it might be a good idea to just clarify that a little? Up to you, you can still have my vote :)